# modify URL with mod_rewrite or hook

Tags: url-rewriting, hooks, mod-rewrite

i'm trying to achieve the following:

user enters this URL into browser

`http://mydomain.com/boston/categoryname/postname/`

i then want to get the first "folder" and check whether or not it's "boston" or "newyork" - if yes, then remove this part of the URL, add it as an query-parameter and pass the modified URL on to wordpress:

`http://mydomain.com/categoryname/postname/?location=boston`

i tried this using apache's `mod_rewrite` like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(boston|newyork)/(.*)$ /$2?location=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

in my `functions.php` i add a filter for `request`

```
add_filter('request', 'request_it');
function request_it($query_vars) 
{
    print_r($query_vars);
}
```

it echos

```
Array ( 
        [page] => 
        [name] => postname 
        [category_name] => boston/categoryname 
        [location] => boston 
)
```

so the location gets passed on as a query-parameter but the `REQUEST_URI` is still `/boston/categoryname/postname/` instead of `/categoryname/postname/` and wordpress tries to display the wrong content.

how can i really strip the location from the URL?
is `mod_rewrite` not the right thing to use?
is there a function where WP evaluates the URLs that are passed to it where i can hook into and look for my `location`?

Comment: i just found out about the `[R]` flag for `RewriteRule` but this really redirects the user and changes the look of the url (`http://himbeer/asdasdasd/?location=berlin`) - not what i wanted ... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed it using the apache proxy module:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !location
RewriteRule ^(boston|newyork)/$ /index.php?location=$1 [NC,QSA,P]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !location
RewriteRule ^(boston|newyork)/(.*)$ /$2?location=$1 [NC,QSA,P]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

the `[P]` option does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I am on similar turf. See:
[flexible rewrite 'ramble' URLs with Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48481)
And no, [R] or 301 redirects won't get you there.
And any regular htaccess rewrite causes trouble, because some part of WPstill helps himself to the original REQUEST_URI (or maybe PATH_INFO).

Did you notice, that you can override $_SERVER variables? (even if that screams hacking)

```
echo "server".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //get's you: the original thing
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = 'banana';
echo "server".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //gets you: banana
```

If you figure out something, please post it.

Comment: i did find a solution - posted it as an answer below.